# Firestore Firebase queries returning no data

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm having issues retrieving data from firestore.
I have a firebase function that I need to call to get archived orders for a certain year_month combination.

The function is the following:

```js
exports.getArchivedOrders = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { clientId, yearMonth } = req.query;

        console.log(`Fetching archived orders for clientId: ${clientId}, yearMonth: ${yearMonth}`);

        const archiveRef = admin.firestore().collection("clients").doc(clientId).collection("archive").doc(yearMonth);

        const archiveDocSnapshot = await archiveRef.get();

        if (archiveDocSnapshot.exists) {
            console.log(`Archive data exists: ${JSON.stringify(archiveDocSnapshot.data())}`);
            const allOrders = [];

            const dateData = archiveDocSnapshot.data();
            for (const dateKey of Object.keys(dateData)) {
                console.log(`Checking orders for date: ${dateKey}`);
                const dateOrdersRef = archiveRef.collection(dateKey);

                const dateOrdersSnapshot = await dateOrdersRef.get();

                dateOrdersSnapshot.forEach((orderDoc) => {
                    console.log(`Order Document Data: ${JSON.stringify(orderDoc.data())}`);
                    allOrders.push(orderDoc.data());
                });
            }

            console.log(`Fetched ${allOrders.length} orders`);
            res.status(200).json(allOrders);
        } else {
            console.log("No data found in archive");
            res.status(404).send("Data not found");
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error getting archived orders:", error);
        res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
    }
});
```

That function returns the following logs when ran:

> DEBUG 2023-11-26T20:07:09.024972944Z Function execution started
> DEFAULT 2023-11-26T20:07:09.075938Z Fetching archived orders for clientId: Nnw2dCPyPiVEN3MQAynNGVoTz3D3, yearMonth: 2023_11
> DEFAULT 2023-11-26T20:07:10.360168Z Archive data exists: {}
> DEFAULT 2023-11-26T20:07:10.360302Z Fetched 0 orders
> DEBUG 2023-11-26T20:07:10.364855559Z Function execution took 1339 ms, finished with status code: 200

The thing is, when I query that location via firestore console at the query builder, it does show the data:

> Query scope: Collection
> Path: /clients/Nnw2dCPyPiVEN3MQAynNGVoTz3D3/archive/2023_11/19

Image showing the orders retrieved with that query, what should also be returned from the firebase function:

[image]

It's basically like it does not retrieve the data inside of the collections or docs that I need, only returning {}.

The data structure in my db is the following with actual examples:

```
clients (collection)
  Nnw2dCPyPiVEN3MQAynNGVoTz3D3 (clientId, document)
    archive (collection)
      2023_11 (document)
        19 (date, collection)
          -Njd8M1YLqUlRsU3vUy3 (orderId, document)
            {key value fields of order data}
          -Njd8N1FTCStqNPNHQkg (orderId, document)
            {key value fields of order data}
          -Njd8Okc9T5-uvh2dCEJ (orderId, document)
            {key value fields of order data}
          -Njd8QWSWo1nR99JDlT9 (orderId, document)
            {key value fields of order data}
          -Njd8RULgTLi22EYO5hp (orderId, document)
            {key value fields of order data}
          -Njd8XV_bDF0i5-kGGwS (orderId, document)
            {key value fields of order data}
```

What could be causing the issue of the function not returning the data?

Does anyone know where it's going wrong?

I'm using this firebase function for my flutter application and tried also many versions of querying the DB from firestore on flutter, but I got the same results.
For some reason this specifically is causing issues, because I've used other functions to write and read other data, all be it maybe not nested as deep as this is. All the others worked without issue, so not sure why this is not working.
Also, I've fully set back my rules for the DB to this to see if there were any issues there, but no:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true; // Be cautious with this, only for testing
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT:
I tried adding a normal key value pair under 2023_11 so there'd ne something else besides the date collections, and after adding test: "test", when running the function, I got the following logs:

> DEBUG 2023-11-26T21:30:16.189294333Z Function execution started
> DEFAULT 2023-11-26T21:30:16.259020Z Fetching archived orders for
> clientId: Nnw2dCPyPiVEN3MQAynNGVoTz3D3, yearMonth: 2023_11
> DEFAULT 2023-11-26T21:30:17.576618Z Archive data exists: {"test":"test"}
> DEFAULT 2023-11-26T21:30:17.576687Z Checking orders for date: test
> DEFAULT 2023-11-26T21:30:17.806408Z Fetched 0 orders
> DEBUG 2023-11-26T21:30:17.826782314Z Function execution took 1637 ms,
> finished with status code: 200

So, it retrieves the key value pairs but not the date collections or any of their info? Why would that be the case and how would I retrieve them otherwise?

---

EDIT: tested iterating through each day of a month to see if it'd work like that and it does, but the performance is very bad, only 6 orders in 1 date and it took 18+sec to complete... any way to improve on this? Like what I initially tried to do so to pull all data for that month in 1 time instead of having to query 31 times for each day of a month?

that code produced the following logs:

> DEBUG 2023-11-26T21:46:40.709930780Z Function execution started
>
> DEFAULT 2023-11-26T21:46:40.721388Z Fetching archived orders for
> clientId: Nnw2dCPyPiVEN3MQAynNGVoTz3D3, yearMonth: 2023_11
>
> DEFAULT 2023-11-26T21:46:44.124408Z Archive data exists:
> {"test":"test"}
>
> DEFAULT 2023-11-26T21:46:44.124448Z Checking orders for date: 1
>
> DEFAULT 2023-11-26T21:46:45.095931Z Checking orders for date: 2
>
> DEFAULT 2023-11-26T21:46:45.782260Z Checking orders for date: 3
>
> DEFAULT 2023-11-26T21:46:45.951621Z Checking orders for date: 4
>
> DEFAULT 2023-11-26T21:46:46.118081Z Checking orders for date: 5
>
> DEFAULT 2023-11-26T21:46:46.278593Z Checking orders for date: 6
>
> DEFAULT 2023-11-26T21:46:46.445759Z Checking orders for date: 7
>
> DEFAULT 2023-11-26T21:46:47.135799Z Checking orders for date: 8
>
> DEFAULT 2023-11-26T21:46:47.818726Z Checking orders for date: 9
>
> DEFAULT 2023-11-26T21:46:48.498045Z Checking orders for date: 10
>
> DEFAULT 2023-11-26T21:46:49.184324Z Checking orders for date: 11
>
> DEFAULT 2023-11-26T21:46:49.880046Z Checking orders for date: 12
>
> DEFAULT 2023-11-26T21:46:50.551128Z Checking orders for date: 13
>
> DEFAULT 2023-11-26T21:46:50.780508Z Checking orders for date: 14
>
> DEFAULT 2023-11-26T21:46:51.461629Z Checking orders for date: 16
>
> DEFAULT 2023-11-26T21:46:51.618238Z Checking orders for date: 17
>
> DEFAULT 2023-11-26T21:46:51.783005Z Checking orders for date: 18
>
> DEFAULT 2023-11-26T21:46:52.475522Z Checking orders for date: 19
>
> DEFAULT 2023-11-26T21:46:52.826810Z Order Document Data:
> {"Status":"Delivered","completedAt":"19-11-2023
> 22:49","role":"client","totalPriceString":"12.00
> EUR","businessLocation":{"address":"Spoorweglaan 87 bus 11, 9470
> Denderleeuw","name":"Cafe 1"},"totalPriceInt":12,"fullName":"Ardian
> Nuhiji","products":{"Glaçons":2},"createdAt":"19-11-2023
> 20:53","uid":"Nnw2dCPyPiVEN3MQAynNGVoTz3D3","phoneNumber":"0486386944","priceCategory":1,"prices":{"Glaçons":6},"email":"test@hotmail.com"}
>
> DEFAULT 2023-11-26T21:46:52.826886Z Order Document Data:
> {"Status":"Delivered","completedAt":"19-11-2023
> 22:49","role":"client","totalPriceString":"12.00
> EUR","businessLocation":{"address":"Spoorweglaan 87 bus 11, 9470
> Denderleeuw","name":"Cafe 1"},"totalPriceInt":12,"fullName":"Ardian
> Nuhiji","products":{"Glaçons":2},"createdAt":"19-11-2023
> 20:53","uid":"Nnw2dCPyPiVEN3MQAynNGVoTz3D3","phoneNumber":"0486386944","priceCategory":1,"prices":{"Glaçons":6},"email":"test@hotmail.com"}
>
> DEFAULT 2023-11-26T21:46:52.830860Z Order Document Data:
> {"Status":"Delivered","completedAt":"19-11-2023
> 22:49","role":"client","totalPriceString":"12.00
> EUR","businessLocation":{"address":"Spoorweglaan 87 bus 11, 9470
> Denderleeuw","name":"Cafe 1"},"totalPriceInt":12,"fullName":"Ardian
> Nuhiji","products":{"Glaçons":2},"createdAt":"19-11-2023
> 20:53","uid":"Nnw2dCPyPiVEN3MQAynNGVoTz3D3","phoneNumber":"0486386944","priceCategory":1,"prices":{"Glaçons":6},"email":"test@hotmail.com"}
>
> DEFAULT 2023-11-26T21:46:52.830906Z Order Document Data:
> {"Status":"Delivered","completedAt":"19-11-2023
> 22:48","role":"client","totalPriceString":"18.00
> EUR","businessLocation":{"address":"Spoorweglaan 87 bus 11, 9470
> Denderleeuw","name":"Cafe 1"},"totalPriceInt":18,"fullName":"Ardian
> Nuhiji","products":{"Glaçons":3},"createdAt":"19-11-2023
> 20:54","uid":"Nnw2dCPyPiVEN3MQAynNGVoTz3D3","phoneNumber":"0486386944","priceCategory":1,"prices":{"Glaçons":6},"email":"test@hotmail.com"}
>
> DEFAULT 2023-11-26T21:46:52.830940Z Order Document Data:
> {"Status":"Cancelled","completedAt":"19-11-2023
> 22:49","role":"client","totalPriceString":"12.00
> EUR","businessLocation":{"address":"Spoorweglaan 87 bus 11, 9470
> Denderleeuw","name":"Cafe 1"},"totalPriceInt":12,"fullName":"Ardian
> Nuhiji","products":{"Glaçons":2},"createdAt":"19-11-2023
> 20:54","uid":"Nnw2dCPyPiVEN3MQAynNGVoTz3D3","phoneNumber":"0486386944","priceCategory":1,"prices":{"Glaçons":6},"email":"test@hotmail.com"}
>
> DEFAULT 2023-11-26T21:46:52.831037Z Order Document Data:
> {"Status":"Delivered","completedAt":"19-11-2023
> 22:49","role":"client","totalPriceString":"60.00
> EUR","businessLocation":{"address":"Spoorweglaan 87 bus 11, 9470
> Denderleeuw","name":"Cafe 1"},"totalPriceInt":60,"fullName":"Ardian
> Nuhiji","products":{"Glaçons":10},"createdAt":"19-11-2023
> 20:53","uid":"Nnw2dCPyPiVEN3MQAynNGVoTz3D3","phoneNumber":"0486386944","priceCategory":1,"prices":{"Glaçons":6},"email":"test@hotmail.com"}
>
> DEFAULT 2023-11-26T21:46:52.831062Z Checking orders for date: 20
>
> DEFAULT 2023-11-26T21:46:53.507662Z Checking orders for date: 21
>
> DEFAULT 2023-11-26T21:46:53.656387Z Checking orders for date: 22
>
> DEFAULT 2023-11-26T21:46:54.321460Z Checking orders for date: 23
>
> DEFAULT 2023-11-26T21:46:55.012932Z Checking orders for date: 24
>
> DEFAULT 2023-11-26T21:46:55.182317Z Checking orders for date: 25
>
> DEFAULT 2023-11-26T21:46:55.847009Z Checking orders for date: 26
>
> DEFAULT 2023-11-26T21:46:56.524597Z Checking orders for date: 27
>
> DEFAULT 2023-11-26T21:46:56.684327Z Checking orders for date: 28
>
> DEFAULT 2023-11-26T21:46:57.359105Z Checking orders for date: 29
>
> DEFAULT 2023-11-26T21:46:58.032666Z Checking orders for date: 30
>
> DEFAULT 2023-11-26T21:46:58.780466Z Checking orders for date: 31
>
> DEFAULT 2023-11-26T21:46:58.932841Z Fetched 6 orders
>
> DEBUG 2023-11-26T21:46:58.937167481Z Function execution took 18227 ms,
> finished with status code: 200

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code in your question, you are fetching a document from Cloud Firestore and then trying to iterate over the collection of documents nested under it. However, your code is expecting Cloud Firestore to behave like the Realtime Database where your request returns the data at the level you requested as well as all the data nested under it. When fetching data in Cloud Firestore, you fetch the document's own data and are not sent any of the nested data.

Additionally, you are using `await` inside a for loop. This should be avoided at all costs when using Cloud Functions as it is only going to drive your costs up processing each request one-by-one. Instead it is more efficient to parallelise the requests and then reassemble the data afterwards.

As you are using Node.JS, you can make use of [`listCollections()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentReference.html#listCollections) to find the collections nested under the desired document.

```js
const { clientId, yearMonth } = req.query;

const archiveDocRef = admin.firestore()
  .collection("clients")
  .doc(clientId)
  .collection("archive")
  .doc(yearMonth);

const archiveColRefs = await archiveRef.listCollections();

if (archiveColRefs.length === 0) {
  res.status(404).send("No data found");
  return;
}

const archiveOrderDataPromises = archiveColRefs.map(async (archiveDateColRef) => {
  const day = Number(archiveDateColRef.id); // for sorting

  const archiveDateQuerySnapshot = await archiveDateColRef.get();

  const ordersOnThisDay = archiveDateQuerySnapshot.docs
    .map(orderDocSnap => orderDocSnap.data());

  // TODO: sort ordersOnThisDay

  console.log(`Day #${day}: Found ${ordersOnThisDay.length} orders.`);

  return {
    day,
    orders: ordersOnThisDay
  }
});

// Promise.allSettled could be used on the next line to make requests
// optional. This will also require more changes below.
const archiveOrderData = await Promise.all(archiveOrderDataPromises);

// sort in place by numeric day (otherwise '10' is sorted before '2')
archiveOrderData.sort((a, b) => a.day - b.day);

// pluck all daily orders arrays into one large array
const allOrders = archiveOrderData
  .flatMap(archiveOrderDataForDay => archiveOrderDataForDay.orders);

console.log(`Total: Found ${allOrders.length} orders.`);
res.status(200).json(allOrders);
```

Notes:

- Your current data model stores order completion and creation times as strings. This will make sorting your orders difficult. Consider using numeric values instead or add numeric values to your model alongside the strings.
- Your current Cloud Function has no authentication steps. This **MUST** be implemented to protect sensitive customer data like phone numbers and emails. Consider switching to a [Callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) to let Firebase handle this for you.
- Error handling of the above code is left as an exercise for the reader.